# Can an anonymous user post a thank-you message or vote?

Tags: support, voting, unregistered-users, thanks

I'm not a registered user but I want to thank or vote for the person who answered my question. Is that possible, or must I register for an account on the website to do so?

Answer (score 8):

If you read the FAQ, you'll see that you must register to vote or comment, and even then you can only vote or comment after you have contributed to the site, which earns you reputation points.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Since you have already registered, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted. This will earn both you and the answerer some reputation points, and you'll be closer to being able to vote up or down. You can also answer other people's questions to earn reputation.

Comment: I haven't already register :D

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a google account, "registering" is probably a misnomer.  If I recall correctly, it's a process of minimal typing & a few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to register. Since the process is quick and can use existing accounts like Facebook or google, what do you have to lose?

Comment: ah ok, no I was just curious.. ok i'll do it later